# Do all operations in the modern software boil down to arithmetic operations and data movements

Tags: software, computer-science

Is it fair to assume that all or most operations in modern software like mouse movements, keyboard events, working with a browser and its controls, playing a game etc. come down to arithmetic/logical operations and data movements?

I've come to this conclusion after looking at the [Instructions Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture#Instruction_types) of modern processors:

1. **Data handling and memory operations**
2. **Arithmetic and logic operations**
3. Control flow operations

Comment: What conclusion are you trying to reach?

Comment: @whatsisname, that whatever code I write in higher level languages like C++ or Java, it will always come down to any of the three types of instructions

Comment: Fun fact: [the x86 mov instruction is Turing-complete (PDF)](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~sd601/papers/mov.pdf). Someone went and turned that into a [mov-only compiler](https://github.com/xoreaxeaxeax/movfuscator)

Comment: If you define the three categories broadly enough, then yes.

Comment: Everything that a modern computer's main processor chip does essentially boils down to simple math, making yes/no decisions and moving data around, as you've already correctly concluded by looking at the instruction sets.

Comment: You may find the broad discussion of minimal ISA's in the article [One instruction set computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_instruction_set_computer) of interest.

Comment: @ErikEidt: Well, if you really want to go that far down, every computer is essentially an elaborate series of on-off switches.

Comment: Arithmetic is really just logic and so is control flow.  So really it comes down to data and logic.

Comment: no amount of maths is going to make your mouse move